# void cannot be converted to Void in function map

Tags: java

My problem is at removeDuplicates(C), why it doesn't accept it this way? Also, can somebody explain how stream works?

```
List<String> countries = new ArrayList<String>() { 
    {
        add("Indiaaaa");
        add("Rommania");
        add("UUUUK");
    }
};
countries.stream()
    .map(c -> removeDuplicates(c))
    .forEach(n -> System.out.print(n + " "));
}
```

And here is the function removeDuplicates:

```
public static void removeDuplicates(String s) {
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    Set<Character> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for(Character c : chars) {
        result.add(c);
    }
    result.forEach(n -> System.out.print(n));
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you expect to happen and what actually happens.   If you do not, how can anyone help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`removeDuplicates` has no return value.  That's what `void` means.  Therefore you can't `map` with it.

The way you've written it, the closest thing to what I *think* you mean would be

```
countries.stream().forEach(country -> {
   removeDuplicates(country); // prints out the letters without duplicates
                              // doesn't actually modify country,
                              // or return the deduplicated characters
   System.out.print(" ");
});
```

...although you could also remove `.stream()`, and just write `countries.forEach(...)`.